# LoRa communication between ESP8266 and RPi 3B+

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi3, esp8266, lora

I have an ESP8266 and a RPI 3B+ both equipped with LoRa-02 (SX1278) modules. I'm trying to send a packet from the ESP to the RPi, but it's not working.

Please consider the following code snippet on ESP8266:

`main.cpp`

```
#include "loRaComms.h"
void setup() {
  // sender
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initLoRa(434800000);
}

void loop() {
  // sender
  brodcastBuffer();
  delay(1000);
}
```

`loRaComms.cpp`

```
#include <LoRa.h>

void initLoRa(int freq) {
  LoRa.setPins(Lora_NSS, Lora_RESET, Lora_DIO0);
  LoRa.setFrequency(freq);
  LoRa.setSignalBandwidth(62500);
  LoRa.setSpreadingFactor(12);
  LoRa.setCodingRate4(8);
  LoRa.setGain(0);
  LoRa.setPreambleLength(6);
  if (!LoRa.begin(freq)) {
    // initialize ratio at 915 MHz  433E6 - Asia, 866E6 - Europe, 915E6 - North America
    Serial.println("LoRa init failed.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("LoRa init succeeded.");
  }
}

void brodcastBuffer() {
  LoRa.beginPacket(); // start packet
  LoRa.print("hello!");
  LoRa.endPacket();
}
```

I have no problem with the ESP8266 code. I have tested this code with 2 ESP8266, one sender and one receiver, everything is working fine!

Now let's see the RPi 3B+ code. I have used [this repository][1] with its own sample code as follows:

````
void * rx_f(void *p) {
  rxData *rx = (rxData *)p;
  printf("rx done \n");
  printf("CRC error: %d\n", rx->CRC);
  printf("Data size: %d\n", rx->size);
  printf("string: %s\n", rx->buf); // Data we've received
  printf("RSSI: %d\n", rx->RSSI);
  printf("SNR: %f\n", rx->SNR);
  free(p);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  LoRa_ctl modem;
  // See for typedefs, enumerations and there values in LoRa.h header file
  modem.spiCS = 0; // Raspberry SPI CE pin number
  modem.rx.callback = rx_f;
  modem.eth.preambleLen = 6;
  modem.eth.bw = BW62_5; // Bandwidth 62.5KHz
  modem.eth.sf = SF12; // Spreading Factor 12
  modem.eth.ecr = CR8; // Error coding rate CR4/8
  modem.eth.freq = 434800000; // 434.8MHz
  modem.eth.resetGpioN = 27; // GPIO4 on lora RESET pin
  modem.eth.dio0GpioN = 17; // GPIO17 on lora DIO0 pin to control Rxdone and Txdone interrupts
  modem.eth.outPower = OP20; // Output power
  modem.eth.powerOutPin = PA_BOOST; // Power Amplifier pin
  modem.eth.AGC = 1; // Auto Gain Control
  modem.eth.OCP = 240; // 45 to 240 mA. 0 to turn off protection
  modem.eth.implicitHeader = 0; // Explicit header mode
  modem.eth.syncWord = 0x12;
  printf("%d\n", modem.eth.bw);
  printf("%d\n", modem.eth.ecr);
  // For detail information about SF, Error Coding Rate, Explicit header, Bandwidth, AGC, Over current protection and other features refer to sx127x datasheet https:// www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/DS_SX127$

  LoRa_begin(&modem);
  LoRa_receive(&modem);

  while (1) {
    usleep(200000);
  }
  printf("end\n");
  LoRa_end(&modem);
}```

But I can't receive anything on RPi. I also tested the ping pong sample on two RPi 3 and it didn't work.

Did I miss something here? I'm open to use any alternative library on RPi3, but I can only use C/C++ libraries. I've used the following pins:

    raspi                       LoRa
    GPIO27, pin13               RESET
    GPIO17, pin 11              DIO0
    MOSI (GPIO10, pin 19)       MOSI
    MISO (GPIO9, pin 21)        MISO
    CLK (GPIO11, pin 23)        SCK
    SPI_CE0 (GPIO8, pin 24)     NSS


  [1]: https://%20github.com/YandievRuslan/sx1278-LoRa-RaspberryPi.git
````

Comment: If you test between two RPI3s and didn't work, then this question has nothing to do with ESP8266.

Comment: @hcheung Do you have any thoughts on RPI3 code, or any alternative?

Comment: Since the product using SPI, so have you enable the SPI?  what do you see if you type `ls -l /dev/spidev*`?

Comment: I've enabled SPI from raspi-config. the output is 
`crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Oct 31 21:17 /dev/spidev0.0`
`crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 1 Oct 31 21:17 /dev/spidev0.1 `

Comment: `modem.spiCS = 0;` Are you sure?

Comment: @dda I've updated my questions ,i have used the SPI0  if i'm right.

Comment: If SPI_CE0 is  (GPIO8, pin 24), Shouldn't `modem.spiCS =0` be `modem.spiCS = 8`?

Comment: @hcheung I suspected this line but anything except 0/1 would cause an error as follow : `2022-11-05 06:55:02 spiOpen: bad spiChan (8)`
`2022-11-05 06:55:02 spiXfer: bad handle (-76)`
I think it is asking for SPI Channel which is 0 or 1 on raspberry pi

Comment: NSS is GPIO8, modem.spiCS should be 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your pin connection

[image]

The PI 3 MISO is GPIO09 and MOSI is GPIO10.
So you need change the pin connection to the following

```
raspi                       LoRa

MOSI (GPIO10, pin 19)       MISO

MISO (GPIO9, pin 21)        MOSI
```

Here is the introduction of SPI MOSI and MISO
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/introduction-to-spi-interface.html